# Oracle SQL: How to get distinct values of a particular column from 5 different tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 5 different tables and one column is common in all 5 tables.
I need 50 distinct values of that column in 1st table, in second table I need 50 distinct values of that same column which does not appear in the list of 50 values I received in the result from 1st table. In this way, I need 250 UNIQUE values from 5 tables. I cannot use a temporary table since I don't have write access in the database and can use only SELECT.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem? Any help or pointers are highly appreciated!

Example: Suppose I have 5 tables Employees, Greenhouse_emp, redhouse_emp, bluehouse_emp, yellowhouse_emp and greyhouse_emp;

The column common in 5 tables is emp_id.

I want 50 distinct emp_ids from greenhouse_emp table, 50 distinct from redhouse_emp which are not including the 50 selected from greenhouse_emp table and so on..

The end result should be 250 employees having 50 distinct of each catagories.

Comment: Don't include 'Urgent' in the title — or the question body.  There is little that puts people's back up quicker than that.  All else apart, it won't be urgent tomorrow, let alone in a year's time.

Comment: please provide some more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

first look at that link to see how joins work. the visual representation is helpful. what you are asking is you want 5 tables joined off of one common column.. but the values you want are distinct for each table.. to do this you need an `outer join` (see examples) and then `select distinct` values `from` the tables by including `where table.id is null`

a sample select would be like this

```
SELECT
    a.whatever,
    b.whatever,
    c.whatever,
    d.whatever,
    e.whatever
FROM(
    SELECT
        a.id as a_id,
        a.whatever
    FROM a.table
    WHERE b.id is null AND c.id is null AND d.id is null AND e.id is null
    LIMIT 50
    ) AS temp
FULL OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT
        b.id as b_id,
        b.whatever
    FROM b.table
    WHERE a.id IS null AND c.id IS null AND d.id IS null AND e.id IS null
    LIMIT 50
    ) AS temp1 ON temp1.b_id = temp.a_id
```

.... you do the rest for the other 3 tables.

I believe this would work, but don't have any way to test it since you didn't provide much. at least this will get you on the right track for doing this with just SELECT's

let me know if this is helpful and if you still have questions. Good Luck!

---

try this first to see if it works with what you have.

```
    SELECT
        e.emp_id as e_id
    FROM employees e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Greenhouse_emp g_e ON g_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN redhouse_emp r_e ON r_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bluehouse_emp b_e ON b_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yellowhouse_emp y_e ON y_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    WHERE g_e.emp_id is null AND r_e.emp_id is null AND b_e.emp_id is null AND y_e.emp_id is null
    LIMIT 50
```

---

Well i don't know if the query works, kinda still waiting on a response from you. but I went ahead and built the whole thing. this is a pretty gross SQL SELECT and is not how I would recommend doing it but with your parameters its all I can think of at the moment.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM(
        SELECT
        e.emp_id as e_id
    FROM employees e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Greenhouse_emp g_e ON g_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN redhouse_emp r_e ON r_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bluehouse_emp b_e ON b_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yellowhouse_emp y_e ON y_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    WHERE g_e.emp_id is null AND r_e.emp_id is null AND b_e.emp_id is null AND y_e.emp_id is null
    LIMIT 50
) AS t
UNION(
    SELECT
        g_e.emp_id as g_id
    FROM Greenhouse_emp g_e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e ON g_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN redhouse_emp r_e ON r_e.emp_id = g_e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bluehouse_emp b_e ON b_e.emp_id = g_e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yellowhouse_emp y_e ON y_e.emp_id = g_e.emp_id
    WHERE e.emp_id is null AND r_e.emp_id is null AND b_e.emp_id is null AND y_e.emp_id is null
    LIMIT 50
) 
UNION(
    SELECT
        r_e.emp_id as r_id
    FROM redhouse_emp r_e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Greenhouse_emp g_e ON g_e.emp_id = r_e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e ON r_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bluehouse_emp b_e ON b_e.emp_id = r_e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yellowhouse_emp y_e ON y_e.emp_id = r_e.emp_id
    WHERE g_e.emp_id is null AND e.emp_id is null AND b_e.emp_id is null AND y_e.emp_id is null
    LIMIT 50
) 
UNION(
    SELECT
        b_e.emp_id as b_id
    FROM bluehouse_emp b_e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Greenhouse_emp g_e ON g_e.emp_id = b_e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN redhouse_emp r_e ON r_e.emp_id = b_e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e ON b_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yellowhouse_emp y_e ON y_e.emp_id = b_e.emp_id
    WHERE g_e.emp_id is null AND r_e.emp_id is null AND e.emp_id is null AND y_e.emp_id is null
    LIMIT 50
)
UNION(
    SELECT
        y_e.emp_id as y_id
    FROM yellowhouse_emp y_e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Greenhouse_emp g_e ON g_e.emp_id = y_e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN redhouse_emp r_e ON r_e.emp_id = y_e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bluehouse_emp b_e ON b_e.emp_id = y_e.emp_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e ON y_e.emp_id = e.emp_id
    WHERE g_e.emp_id is null AND r_e.emp_id is null AND b_e.emp_id is null AND e.emp_id is null
    LIMIT 50
);
```

this query should return 1 columns with 250 id's. 
I used union to add all to one column... if the id is the same in more than one of the subquery then the results will be less than 250 rows returned (a good way to test). if I could test it it would be much simpler lol. let me know if this is closer to what you want.

Comment: I just added few more details, could you check please and give me the full query! Thanks so much for help..

Comment: the full query is an exact repeat of the FULL OUTER JOIN for the last 3 tables. the id would be your emp_id. are you not able to copy that? i.e i can do it for you but its good for you to practice doing it so you learn :) if you can't then comment again and ill finish it

Comment: dont forget to +1 the answer :)

Comment: Hi John,I tried the full one, not giving the result as expected :( can you post the full query?

Comment: Also, I wanted all the results in a single column, with your approach I am getting 5 different columns which is not the correct format for my code :(

Comment: to get it all in one column you need to do that in the other language you are using... like python or java or whatever you are using... to be honest this query is going to be massive. and it will not be efficient at all. i would say run 5 separate selects that pull the data out then build all 5 into a dictionary or list or whatever variable type you want to use to list all in one row

Comment: i just made an edit.. run that query and see if it actually works

Comment: Yes thats what I thought its going to be huge and extremely inefficient :( I have to try doing this in other language it seems..

Comment: Can cursor be used in any way?

Comment: basically you have to do that same query 5 times... if you can do it in a different language it would be simple.. just do that 5 times where you change the id you pull out and compile to one list. cursors can be an option, but its also very slow just less API interaction. I am not super familiar with them so I don't know if you can pull it into one list. but since its pretty late ill give you a query tomorrow that should do what you want it to do

Comment: i think a group by would bring it all to one row and just list 250 rows... since they are all unique... did you run that query? does it work?

Comment: please look at the edited version of the answer and tell me if that is what you want.